# Why is .error() being called when .on() is working? (IE11)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

```
$(function() {  /*jquery .ready()*/
  var thumb_img = new Image();
  thumb_img.id = 'cid_' + 1730;
  thumb_img.src = ""; 

  $(thumb_img).on('load', function() {
    console.log("Image loaded " + thumb_img.src);
  }).error(function(){
    console.log("ERROR loading image " + thumb_img.src);
  });

  thumb_img.src = 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png';
});
```

Result in console:

```
Image loaded https://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png
ERROR loading image https://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png
```

I only want .error() to be called if the image cannot be loaded. This seems to be happening in IE (using 11) only.

Using jquery 2.0.2

Comment: what jQuery version are you using. `error()` is deprecated as of  v1.8 . Try `on('error', handler)` to attach to `error` event instead

Comment: Edited my question to include version (2.0.2). I also tried your code, it did not fix it. `.on('error', function(){console.log("ERROR loading image " + thumb_img.src");});`

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to this line:

```
thumb_img.src = "";
```

Remove the previous line from your code. For IE11 it seems like changing the source attribute and so the error.

```js
var thumb_img = new Image();
thumb_img.id = 'cid_' + 1730;
//thumb_img.src = "";


$(thumb_img).on('load', function() {
    console.log("Image loaded " + thumb_img.src);
}).on('error', function(e){
    alert("ERROR loading image " + thumb_img.src);
});

thumb_img.src ='https://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png';

document.body.appendChild(thumb_img);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `load()` method instead. That way you can look for errors in a callback. This should be fired anytime the `src` attribute of the image is changed. Which technically you are doing right away, hence the error.

```
$('img').load(function(response, status, xhr){
    console.log('loaded');
    console.log({response,status, xhr});
    if (status === "error") {
        console.log('error here');
    }
});

$('img').attr('src', 'someimageurl');
```